# Problema contact_me en php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con el `mail()` en php

Ésto tengo en el php

```js
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])    ||
   empty($_POST['email'])   ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
   }
 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
 
// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'alexisgranja@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Contactado por:  $name";
$email_body = "Te han cotactado desde tu web.\n\n"."Estos son los detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMensage:\n$message";
$mailheader = "Reply-To: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader = "Return-Path: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader = "From: Some One <mydomain@myhost.com>\r\n"; 
$mailheader = "Organization: My Organization\r\n"; 
$mailheader = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"; 

if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$mailheader,"-f {$to}")){ 
echo "Email Enviado.";
} 
else{ echo "Error.";
} 
?>
```

html

```html
<h3>Dejame un mensaje</h3>
      <form method="post" action="contact_me.php" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="email" type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
              <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
          <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar Mensaje</button>
      </form>
```

y por ultimo el java script

```js
$(function() {

    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Mensaje Enviado!!!, Muchas Gracias. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Lo siento " + firstName + ", el servidor de correos no responde. Favor reintente o contacte a alexisgranja@gmail.com !");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

El problema es que desde localhost no envía y me sale error, pero al publicarlo en heroku, sale el mensaje enviado pero no llega nada al correo receptor.

Comment: podrías agregar el error que te sale en tu localhost

Comment: Estás asignando mal la variable `$mailheader`. En lugar de concatenar, estás sobreescribiendo el valor una y otra vez. No sé si eso será causa de error (creo que no debería, aunque no estoy seguro), pero es algo que definitivamente debes corregir

Comment: Éste es el error que sale en localhost, lo raro es que cuando lo subo pues si envía. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: En el JavaScript también tienes algo raro. La url en `url: "././mail/contact_me.php"` puede que sea otro foco de problemas. Básicamente `./` es "en este mismo directorio", con lo cual si haces `././mail/contact_me.php` es lo mismo que `./mail/contact_me.php`. ¿Seguro que esa es la ruta que quieres?